# Saving multiple selected checkboxlist into database asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database, checkboxlist

i'm working with ASP.NET web application and i'm having a problem with adding multiple selected checkboxlist into the database . i want the user to be able to chose more then one Check Box. i have tried some method but it didn't work the database still empty even my database connection work fine with others tables .

`Destinations` table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destinations]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [North] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [West] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [South] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [East] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Destinations_DeliveryMen] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [DeliveryMen]([Delivery_ID])
)
```

and my `CheckBoxList` is :

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="263px">
                <asp:ListItem text="North " Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem text="South " Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem text="West " Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem text="East " Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

UPDATE : 
the C# code that i have tried :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string insertcheckboxlist = "insert into Destinations (North,West,South,East) values(@1,@3,@2,@4))";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insertcheckboxlist, conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckBoxList2", CheckBoxList2.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: You'll get more help if you post the code you used to try and save your output.

Comment: ok but that doesnt trigger your command to be run.. you do have that in your code right?

Comment: comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I think the problem is that your parametrized query expects 4 paramters (@1, @2, @3 and @4), but you are passing only one and that has even a different name (@CheckBoxList2).

Comment: I needed to add `Identity Specification` to the `Id` field and remove the foreign key.

Comment: Also, if you only need to store true/false in each of these fields, I would recommend using a `bit` field in SQL Server instead of the `int` field you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

The `Parameters.AddWithValue` wasn't doing what you thought it was doing. I ended up just building the SQL string manually. FYI, I had to remove the Foreign Key (`FK_Destinations_DeliveryMen`) to get this to work because I had no test data and couldn't get it to work with it. I also had to add `Identity Specification` to the table for the Id field.

This code currently adds -1 to the database for boxes that are checked and 0 where they're not.

Note: There are spaces at the end of the text of you checkboxes (e.g. "North "). Not sure if that was intended but it tripped me up a bit.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

short North = CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByText("North ").Selected;
short West = CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByText("West ").Selected;
short South = CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByText("South ").Selected;
short East = CheckBoxList2.Items.FindByText("East ").Selected;

string insertcheckboxlist = "insert into Destinations (North,West,South,East) values(" + North.ToString + "," + West.ToString + "," + South.ToString + "," + East.ToString + ")";

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insertcheckboxlist, conn);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hopefully, this will get you going. To get this working with `FK_Destinations_DeliveryMen` as part of your table, you'll need to get a valid value that satisfies that foreign key and build it into your `insertcheckboxlist` SQL statement. Of course, we cannot test that for you because we don't have that data and don't understand how it works but that might be a separate question.

Here's the table definition to make this work. As I stated before, I would make `North`, `South`, `East`, and `West` all `bit` fields. If you're able to do it this way, you may make your life easier:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destinations]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [North] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [West] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [South] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    [East] INT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this table.  At first, I thought that you were missing the autonumbering.  Since you are only inserting the values for the four checkboxes and not providing the id field in your insert statement, I thought the autonumbering was missing.

But then I notice that this id has a foreign key defined saying it references deliverymen.deliveryid.  So it should not be autonumbered, but provided by that table.  Which means you have to retrieve it from that table and add it to your insert.  You cannot just insert the four values and expect the id to magically transfer.

By the way, this looks like bad design on this table.  If the table only has those four values and a key referencing that deliverymen table, then most likely these four values just belong in the deliverymen table.  There does not seem to be any reason, from what you have here, to have them in a separate table.

Comment: thanks for this answer ! i have search a lot in this topic and what i got is better to do it in separate tables ! even i want it from the first places to be in 1 table and use in in `Registration` page ! but i didn't know how to do it actually :( i'm still beginner !

Comment: Hmmm, can't imagine why it would be better to be in separate table.  But never mind.  Assuming you have to have these in a separate table, you still have to provide that id in the insert.  Your insert into this table will fail every time if you do not provide that id in your insert statement (assuming the table is defined as you have above).

Comment: they said it's much easier to have it in separate table so the data will be retrieval much easier ! i'm my case i still don't know which method is better !